# Google Apps Free edition user limit

Tags: google-apps

I was setting up Google Apps for a small company (25 employees) and discovered that google want to be paid for each user when your organisation has more than 10 users. I am sure the limit used to be much higher (50 users).

Is there an alternative to using google apps that has similar feature set and can be used for free by a small organisation (25 users)

---

Edit: Additionally...

If I already have an account, can I add another domain as a sub-organisation, and therefore benefit from my existing higher user limit? Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit used to be higher (25-50, though I don't recall for certain) and if the account was set up then, it's grandfathered.

Subdomain's are only available in the paid version, and they'd only get you an alternative domain going to the same inbox, rather than additional addresses.  So you'd be able to have billy@domain.com and billy@subdomain.com, rather than bill@domain.com and billy2@subdomain.com.

I've not seen anything approaching the same features.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an alternative to using google apps that has similar feature set and can be used for free by a small organisation (25 users)

You can use Microsoft's [Live Domains](http://domains.live.com) for a similiar functionality to Google apps. It's free too. However the kind of powerful filters and email customization proivided by Gapps is lacking here.

> If I already have an account, can I add another domain as a sub-organisation, and therefore benefit from my existing higher user limit? Has anyone done this?

Yes you can add any number of additional domains which allow use of the existing unused licenses on one domain's Google apps, or domain aliases which share the inbox of other domains, in Google Apps.